# Go to Web Page and Hand Cursor when rolling over movie clip on Adobe Flash Cs5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs5, ads

Please I want to add a web page link adress on all ad area for my movie clip like google adsense .swf ads, And I want also show hand Cursor when movie clip rolling over on Adobe Flash Cs5 Action Script 3.0,
Please Help,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a button which is on top of everything, full size. It will have hand cursor. Or create MovieClip/Sprite, and use:

```
clip.buttonMode = true;
```

Comment: thank you, and this video is very helpful :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laGxZuHWB14